# R how to extract numeric values from column names in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have very long column names in a data frame. All of them have letters and numbers(0 to 9). How can i extract just the numbers from the column names.

Comment: You can do `library(stringr); str_extract_all(names(df), '[0-9]+')`  Just a reminder, there is no reproducible example or expected result, so it is a broad question and the answer is also broad

Comment: @akrun thanks this works

Comment: Thanks @akrun. one extra step grabs the digits as numbers for me ...

 as.numeric( str_extract_all(names( ...